# Can't insert image in HTML email

Tags: php, html, image, email

I am trying to insert an image in my html email but i get an error when i try to refer to its url. What am i doing wrong? Is there another way to do it? Thank you so much!

```
     <?php
    include "config.php";
    $email= 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Test';

$header= array(
    'From: HackHolyokeTeam@hackholyoke.org',
    'Content-Type: text/html'
               );
$body="

<h1> Title <h1>
<div>
<img src="http://path/to/img/img.jpg">
</div>
<h2> Text 2<h2>

";

mail($email,$subject,$body,implode("\r\n",$header));


echo "email sent!";

    ?>
```

Comment: you are using double quotes, change to single quotes <img src='http://path/to/img/img.jpg'>

Comment: Oh that was it...Thank you! I always use the wrong quotes ..embarrassing.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php <= using that, would have signaled the parse error.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML contains double quotes.  Since you're putting this HTML in a string, the double quotes in the HTML are terminating the string before the actual end of your HTML.

You can escape the double quotes with a backslash, as below:

```
$body="

<h1> Title <h1>
<div>
<img src=\"http://path/to/img/img.jpg\">
</div>
<h2> Text 2<h2>

";
```